# I want to check a string against many different regular expressions at once

Tags: c++, regex, loops

I have a string which the user has inputted and I have my regular expressions within my Database and I can check the input string against those regular expressions within the database fine.

But now I need to add another column within my database which will hold another regular expression but I want to use the same for loop to check the input string againt my new regular expression aswell but at the end of my first loop. But I want to use this new expression against the same string

i.e 
    `\\D\\W\\D`  <-- first expression
    `\\d` <-- second expression which I want to use after the first expression is over

1. use regular expressions from database against input string which works
2. add new regular expression and corporate that within the same loop and check against the same string - not workin

my code  is as follows

```
std::string errorMessages [2][2] = {
    {
        "Correct .R\n",
    },
    {
        "Free text characters out of bounds\n",
    }
};
for(int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++)
{
    if(el[i].substr(0,3) == ".R/")
    {
        DCS_LOG_DEBUG("--------------- Validating .R/ ---------------");
        output.push_back("\n--------------- Validating .R/ ---------------\n");
        str = el[i].substr(3);
        split(st,str,boost::is_any_of("/"));
        DCS_LOG_DEBUG("main loop done");

        for (int split_id = 0 ; split_id < splitMask.size() ; split_id++ )
        {
            boost::regex const string_matcher_id(splitMask[split_id]);
            if(boost::regex_match(st[split_id],string_matcher_id))
            {
                a = errorMessages[0][split_id];
                DCS_LOG_DEBUG("" << a );
            }
            else
            {
                a = errorMessages[1][split_id];
                DCS_LOG_DEBUG("" << a);
            }
            output.push_back(a);
        }
        DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Out of the loop 2");

    }
}
```

How can I retrieve my regular expression from the database and after this loops has finished use this new regex against the same string.

STRING IS - `shamari`
regular expresssion i want to add - `"\\d"`

ask me any questions if you do not understand

Comment: It sounds like you just want to add some more code... did you just try writing it? Your question sounds like quest "how do I do more than 1 thing in my code?"

Comment: yeah i will need to add more code but as you can see i use a loop to loop through the regeex and input string but i just want to add my new regex against that but wen the results are displayed separate them by a title

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you entirely, but if you're asking "How do I combine two separate regexes into a single regex", then you need to do

```
combinedRegex = "(?:" + firstRegex + ")|(?:" + secondRegex + ")"
```

if you want an "or" comparison (either one of the parts must match).

For an "and" comparison it's a bit more complicated, depending on whether these regexes match the entire string or only a substring.

Be aware that if the second regex uses numbered backreferences, this won't work since the indexes will change: `(\w+)\1` and `(\d+)\1` would have to become `(?:(\w+)\1)|(?:(\d+)\2)`, for example.

Comment: Yeah i basically need to combine a regex hm yes for some reason i did not think of that :/ thanks @timpietzcker

Comment: @OP: Note that "combining" involves a boolean operator - in this case a logical "or". Depending on what you're doing, you may want logical "and".

Comment: @tenfour: Thanks for this point; I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Just for future reference, merging a regular expression automatically is actually not trivial. I needed this once and [wrote a library function for it](https://gist.github.com/33251). Unfortunately it’s in PHP but it may still serve as a useful reference.